# dropdown does not work if added with insertUI in Shiny R

Tags: shiny, dropdown

dropdown does not work if added with insertUI in Shiny R.
Please help making it work.

Here is the minimal example code demonstrating the issue:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

    

ui <- fluidPage(
      dropdown(textInput("text", label = NULL, value = "text"),
               icon = icon("table"), label = "works"),
      actionButton("add", "Add content to div2"),
      div(id = "div2")
    )
    
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(selector = "#div2",
             where = "beforeEnd",
             ui = dropdown(textInput("text", label = NULL, value = "text"),
                           icon = icon("table"), label = "does not work"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved by updating shinyWidgets to 0.7.3 and shiny to 1.7.2

Apparently, this was related to a known issue with scripts inside insertUI() and was solved by a recent update.
https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1545